# Facebook Popup interrupt my automation test in Webdriver, i wanna block it

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I actually make "Facebook add friends script", which click twenty times in "Add friend" button. All work wihout problems, but sometimes Facebook popup (Help user "name" find friends) interrupt my script. I have one idea: check in all For loop for display popup, but it's will be very slowly(set sleep.wait(s) and wait for web element loading). 
What is the bes tway to block it? It's only example, i think easy to understand :)

```
friendbuttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(button xpath)
x=0
for friendbutton in friendbuttons:
    wait and check for popup(By popup.is.displayed?)
    if popup display 
       close popup
    else
       friendbutton.click()
       x = x + 1
       print("Add " + str(x) + " friend")
       time.sleep(1)
       if (i > 20):
           break
```

Facebook popup

```html
<div class="_59s7" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="u_13_1" style="width: 480px; margin-top: 40px;"><div class="_4t2a"><div style="opacity: 1;"><div><div class="_4-i0"><div class="clearfix"><div class="_51-u rfloat _ohf"><a class="_42ft _5upp _50zy layerCancel _51-t _50-0 _50z-" role="button" href="#" title="Zamknij" data-testid="dialog_title_close_button">Zamknij</a></div><div><h3 id="u_13_1" class="_52c9"><div class="_1t0"><div class="ptm title fwb">Zasugeruj użytkownikowi Szymon znajomych</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement below:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Zamknij').click()
except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException):
    friendbutton.click()
    ....
```

This should allow to click "Close" button if pop-up appears, otherwise to click "Add friend"

Comment: Work fine, but when facebook show alert, my script inerrupted by error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:

in line: driver.find_element_by_link_text('Zamknij').click()

@Andersson, Thanks man for your big help ;]

Comment: Button could be already present in `DOM`, but visible only when pop-up appears. Try updated answer

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: Zamknij

IN line: driver.find_element_by_link_text('Zamknij').click()

Wtf? So not find element then script must realize except code? Or no?